# tf broadcaster too slow for lookupTransform

Tags: transforms, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,

i create a frame and publish it **once** with broadcaster. after the broadcaster-call I do a lookupTransform. The problem. i am getting not the lookup to the last information i have broadcasted. For me the broadcaster is too slow.

Is there a possibility to transform two frames directly without broadcasting ? or should i set the buffer time very low?

regards

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276984/tf-broadcaster-too-slow-for-lookuptransform/) by [TobiMiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/32819/tobimiller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2017-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you don't care about other nodes being able to access the transforms take a look at BufferCore, which allows offline transforms with a similar interface to tf #q258116

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-11-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [TobiMiller](https://answers.ros.org/users/32819/tobimiller/) on 2017-12-04**:
thx, i found another solution for me :) i check if the transform differs from the last one ;) otherwise i do the lookup again